# Where can C# get AWS credentials with parameterless constructor

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, .net-core, amazon-dynamodb

I am currently maintaining a project written by another team and there is something I haven't been able to understand.

They have integration **tests** connecting to AWS resources like Dynamo, S3 etc. In their code, they use parameterless constructors and apparently the test runs with default credentials.

For example:

```
new AmazonDynamoDBClient();
```

How can achieve connecting with default constructor? Can someone help me with that?

Note: I can't change it to dependency injected model at the moment.

Comment: I've never used AWS before, but a quick Google search of the documentation [says where it pulls the configuration from with the default constructor](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/DynamoDBv2/MDynamoDBctor.html). They also have [directions on how to store credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/net-dg-config-creds.html).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have already come acros this. This is for dotnet framework, but this project is core 3.1. The only way I could find was configuring in the StartUp and injecting into classes. However, they initialized client classes and somehow it knows which credentials to start. I am imagining a kind of configuration making some credentials default for parameterless AWS classes.

Comment: it's probably in appsettings.json

Comment: why don't you step through it in debug mode and see what it is doing to get the credentials?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For local development the credentials are loaded from the [shared config and credentials file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkref/latest/guide/creds-config-files.html) which on your local machine can be set up by using the [`aws configure` cli command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/configure/) with an [AWS Access Key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_access-keys.html). The `aws configure` command will ask for your access key ID, Secret token and a default [region code](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/general/latest/gr/rande.html). Those 3 are required for the parameterless constructor to work, the fourth parameter `Default output format` is optional.

I'd recommend using `aws configure --profile your_profile_name` instead, this gives you the flexibility to use multiple sets of credentials and control which one is used by setting the `AWS_Profile` environment variable. You can do this in your project properties, e.g. using the `launchsettings.json` file with a custom launch profile:

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "LaunchProfileName": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "AWS_PROFILE": "your_profile_name"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There are some other environment variables that can be used as well, see the quote in the end of this post for more options.

When the application is actually deployed to AWS, it will automatically use the [execution role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html) set up for a lambda function (or similar mechanisms for other kinds of services, see the list at the end of this post).

⚠ Please be aware that the shared credentials file will be saved unencrypted at `%USERPROFILE%\.aws\credentials` for Windows and `~/.aws/credentials` on Linux/MacOs. ⚠

For other options to provide credentials please refer to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/latest/developer-guide/net-dg-config-creds.html). Specifically the page about [Credential and profile resolution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/latest/developer-guide/creds-assign.html) is quite helpful:

> Credential search order
>
> Credentials that are explicitly set on the AWS service client, as
> described in Accessing credentials and profiles in an application.
>
> A credentials profile with the name specified by a value in
> AWSConfigs.AWSProfileName.
>
> A credentials profile with the name specified by the AWS_PROFILE
> environment variable.
>
> The [default] credentials profile.
>
> SessionAWSCredentials that are created from the AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
> AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, and AWS_SESSION_TOKEN environment variables, if
> they're all non-empty.
>
> BasicAWSCredentials that are created from the AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and
> AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY environment variables, if they're both
> non-empty.
>
> IAM Roles for Tasks for Amazon ECS tasks.
>
> Amazon EC2 instance metadata.

Comment: I just set AWS_PROFILE and it worked from environment variables. 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome. If it answered your question, feel free to mark my response as answer by clicking the checkmark :)

Comment: I missed that, sorry. But I did it now. Thanks again.